# UML diagram multiplicity and aggregation

Tags: uml, multiplicity

Am I understanding multiplicity and aggregation here?

The Idea I'm trying to get across is that:

- Each character has a spell book.
- Each spell book has an array of 4 spells. (This is where things look a little weird to me)

[image]

Comment: Looks correct to me. You could even argue that the aggregation can be refined to a composition: http://aviadezra.blogspot.de/2009/05/uml-association-aggregation-composition.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's basically ok. The `SpellArr` is a (wrongly placed and capitalized) redundant attribute. Rather you should use dot-notation together with the role name `spell` (which should be `spells` instead). Also the hollow diamond should be removed as it has no useful semantics. See p. 110 of the specs:

> Indicates that the Property has shared aggregation semantics. Precise semantics of shared aggregation varies by application area and modeler.

[image]

Comment: Annoying downvote without providing any justification!

Comment: It seems that the design model for the `Character` class can be simplified by modeling `SpellBook` as a complex datatype with a `spells` property and a `castSpell` method. Then `Character` would simply have a `spellBook` property and there would be no need for an  association.

Comment: @GerdWagner Yeah, but I don't care about down votes any more. That just happens :-/ You are probably right about the design issues, but that would take it too far off. I always found it the most interesting part to scribble the design to a whiteboard and discuss it with others.

Comment: I'll compensate the annoying downvote with an upvote.

Comment: I should look up some of your posts to give you one back :-) Thanks!